# Query problems with a json type in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, types

Hello I have just started working with json type in mysql and I've encountered a problem while trying to do a simple query.

I am using a table called customer which has 3 fields:

```
id type int
name type varchar(50)
attributes type json
```

example of attributes:

```
"attributes": {"id": "5", "plan": "blabla"}
```

I was following a guide on how to query json types and ended up with this query:

```
SELECT attributes ->> 'plan' from customer;
```

the query should return the plan fields of attributes. it works in the guide I'm following however when I do it I end up with this error:

```
 [42000][3143] Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 1.
```

If anyone knows why this is happening?

P.S. I recently upgraded my mysql to 8.0 from 5.7 . Is there any chance that it's the reason of my query not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be the operator is not  ->>'plan'  but

```
SELECT attributes->>"$.plan" from customer;
```